# Control Philips Hue Bulbs with Indoor Geofencing

Tags: android, geofencing, rssi, indoor-positioning-system, philips-hue

for a study project, I have to find out if it's possible to control Philips Hue bulbs indoor based on geolocation.
Philips Hue allows for geofencing via GPS, for example if you leave the house or return, but is it somehow possible to increase the accuracy of the geofencing?
The idea would be to switch the light when leaving a room and entering the next room.

I am at the very beginning of my work and am currently reading through dozens articles about indoor navigation. It seems that the best approach would be a positioning system via RSSI.

In the end there should be an app on the smartphone, that automatically switches the light when the smartphone is in a specific range of the bulb. Biggest problem, as far as I can estimate, is that most smartphones don't support Zigbee (yet).

So before I dive deeper into this issue, I would like to ask, if there is any possible way to achieve this. Is it possile to read the signal strength of the Philips Hue bulbs? Is there maybe another approach that I didn't think of yet?

Even if I would buy a Xbee module and an Arduino board for example, would it be possible to read the RSSI of the bulbs? And would it be possible to use this information in Android in any way?

Does anyone have practical experience with this issue?

I really appreciate every tip / opinion / explanation that you could give me.

Greetings,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Industry standard approach for indoor positioning seems to be RSSI using Bluetooth Low Energy beacons. I would choose this approach and forget about trying to integrate with the Zigbee network unless your project is Zigbee specific.

I've played about with a few BLE beacons. You can alter their transmission power depending upon your need, with the lowest setting resulting in the beacon only being visible to the phone from a few feet away.

With a beacon in each room I don't see why this wouldn't work for you. If the rooms don't have doors between them then maybe a pair of beacons in each room would be more reliable.

BLE support is baked into Android from version 4.3 onwards, it's easy to measure signal strength, estimate distance to beacon etc. Then it's just a case of making REST calls to the bridge depending upon which beacon is closest to the phone. If you have a Raspberry Pi 3 you can configure it to act as a BLE beacon for testing before buying any dedicated beacons.

In terms of Hue integration I would probably set up a new sensor on the bridge for each room and have the phone modify the value of this sensor based on signal strength from each beacon. Then on the bridge I would create rules to react to changes in these sensor values. This would make it easy to deploy an Android app involving minimal code and use the Hue bridge to create more complex conditional rules like what to do if someone walked quickly in and out of a room, handle multiple people in the same room etc.

***Edited to add the following in response to your comment, apologies for the lengthy post!***

Within the Hue API one of the available resources is sensors. If you buy Hue products like motion sensor, light switch etc these are added to the bridge as individual sensors. However you can also create your own generic sensors using the API and use these to store values that you update via the REST interface. The values of your custom sensors can be used in the rules on the bridge as conditions and triggers, you can even read the sensor values via the API to use in your own applications. This is where the system becomes very customisable.

As you are developing using Android I would recommend the Tasker app along with the RESTasker plugin as this provides an easy way to integrate with the Hue bridge and react to BLE sensors.

Here are examples of how I have used sensors in my setup, which works in conjunction with a raspberry pi:

- TV status - My tv has IP control and I have a python script polling
  it every second to see if it is switched on or off. When this value
  changes the python script updates the TV status sensor on my Hue
  bridge.
- Home sensors for each member of the family - I have a 433mhz door
  switch on the front door of my house. Whenever the door is opened
  this triggers a delayed python script which pings the (static) IP
  addresses of the phone of each member of the household on the LAN to
  work out who is at home. It then sets the Home sensor value in the
  bridge for everyone who is at home to 1.
- Overnight we use wireless chargers, when each phone is placed on a
  wireless charger it updates the home sensor value for that person
  from 1 to 2.

So from these few custom sensors the bridge can now trigger rules based on who is at home, whether they are in bed or not and whether or not the TV is on. Some of my rules are:

- If the living room lights are on and the TV is switched on dim the
  lights, if the TV is switched off increase the brightness again. If
  the TV is on and the light level outside is 0 (read from Hue motion
  sensor outside) then slowly change the bulb hue to red.
- Turn off all the lights once the last person in the house puts their
  phone on it's wireless charger. A python script also turns off the TV
  off it has been left on.
- When I put my phone on the wireless charger a Tasker task reads the
  home variable for my daughter from the bridge. It then sets my alarm
  later than normal if she is not here, as I don't have to take her to
  school.
- If I'm connected to my home wifi and my phone rings or I make a call
  a Tasker task reads the sensor variables. If nobody else is at home
  and the TV is on Tasker sends the IP command to my TV to mute the
  volume, once the call ends it unmutes it again.

In terms of approaching your project I would create a sensor on the bridge to go with each room in the house, set with an initial value of 0. Then in Tasker I would scan for the closest BLE sensor. Lets say the closest BLE sensor is living room, I would have Tasker read the living room sensor variable from the bridge (value is 0) and then add 1 to the value and write it back to the bridge (value is now 1). I would have Tasker save a variable that the last sensor updated was living room and keep scanning for BLE beacons. Now if Tasker finds a different BLE beacon which is closer than living room I would have it read the living room sensor from the bridge again (still 1), subtract 1 from the value and write it back (so now its 0) and then repeat the process above, adding 1 to the sensor value for the room the phone is now closest to.
In the bridge I would have rules that said if sensor value for a room = 0 turn off lights in that room, if sensor value > 0 turn on lights in that room. Because you are reading the existing value and adding or subtracting from it when a phone enters a room the system can cope with multiple phones/people in the house. If two people are in a room then the room sensor value will be 2 so the lights will only turn off when the last person leaves, not if one of them goes to get a drink or whatever.

As you can tell I've spent far too long tinkering with my Hue, but it's been a great learning process. I came to it knowing very little about programming at all and found the API very easy to understand, it's flexibility and ease of integration with other things inspired me to become proficient in several languages and make some cool projects along the way.

Comment: Woah, thank you very much for this ideas / explanations! I will definitely go for this direction. I understand the main principle of your approach, but what do you mean with "set up a sensor on the bridge for each room"?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more information, hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! First, let me thank you for the time and effort you put into the answer. This really helps me a lot to understand the generell workflow for this project. Second, I just got some extra motivation for my project due to your statements. Thank you for that. :)

Comment: You're welcome. When I started out coding I spent hours on this website looking for answers about how to do just about everything. It's good to be able to help someone else for a change. Let me know how you get on with your project, I would be interested to hear what you come up with.

Comment: I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you remember our little conversation here, but I wanted just to tell you about this project. I had many problems during the time and the project has changed greatly.
To be honest, the whole project hasn't much to do with my original question anymore :D

Today I finished the work on the project (it was for my master thesis) and came up with an application that is able to record and control Hue lamps by pointing on them, based on Beacon Regions. So if a supported region is entered and the smartphone is pointed at a Hue lamp, a button can be clicked to save the values "UUID", "Major", "Minor", "LightID", "Room name", "Pointing direction" and "Pointing tilt" (based on the values from the smartphone sensors).

Afterwards, to control the lights, the saved data is processed into JSON format. If the smartphone then is pointed towards one of the lights and the recorded data (values in JSON file) matches the actual real time values (Region, Hue light ID, Direction, etc.), then the lamp is controllable and can be switched on/off on a button click.

So instead of switching the light on and off based on proximity to the lamp (as I talked about in my inital question), the switching now can take place from any point inside the defined region after this points are recorded the first time the app is used.

I wanted to thank you again for your help when the project started, especially the information about how to control and work with the bridge was my entry point into the project and helped me a lot!

Greetings!

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw this. Thanks for the update, it sounds like your end result turned out to be a more impressive implementation than your initial goal. Is the project purely academic or are you actually using it yourself? The solution for room monitoring that I've settled on is to monitor power consumption of other devices in the rooms and use those figures to determine if someone is in the room or not. Works well for me and has the added advantage of being fully automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add some info that is missed by miknik and I don't have the reputation to comment yet...

First the beacons referenced are not BLE, they are 802.15.4 beacons and are supported by ZigBee, Z-Wave, Bluetooth, BLE, Wifi, etc. They're a fantastic resource for exactly this kind of project, however not all devices are required to support beacons, it depends on the protocol (Zigbee, etc) and on the developer of the product (in this industry everyone loves to cut corners).

Second using RSSI is immensely variable otherwise people would have long ago been geolocating via these values. Even if you take the simplest approach and only use the RSSI value to determine distance from a device that value can fluctuate +-100% just based on wiring, other devices present or active, your body, etc. Technically even certain weather and astrological phenomena will affect this. To that end most approaches integrate the LQI value which indicates the link quality to influence how reliable they think the RSSI is. The LQI is reportable along with the RSSI.

The rest of miknik's strategy is pretty good given what you have to work with.

Comment: The [beacons I referenced](https://developers.google.com/beacons/) are BLE. They operate in the same frequency range as 802.15.4 devices, but there are several differences in terms of data rates, modulation, bandwidth and network models. The 802.15.4 protocol specifies 2 network topologies, p2p (can be expanded to mesh) or star. The relevant difference is 802.15.4 implements request/confirm communication between devices whereas BLE beacons blindly transmit advertising packets and are unable to connect to or receive any data from client devices. Clients remain anonymous and cant be tracked.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with BLE specifics to know if for some reason they are using the exact same name for a different packet type, but ZigBee and ZWave both have blind beacons. They can be used to find networks and such but don't allow any actual data to be communicated which sounds exactly like what you're getting at with "advertising packets".